# selecting an itemid of a actionsheet to hide/destroy it

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to select an ActionSheet with the itemId of options. I've tried many selectors but the documentation isn't the best and I am lost about how can I select the itemId of the ActionSheet.

thanks

```
Ext.define('crystal.controller.view', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            test: {
                selector: 'test #viewapphb',
            },
            actionsheet: {
                selectors: 'options',
                xtype: 'test',
                autoCreate: true,
            }
        },
        control: {

            test: {
                tap: 'viewapphb',
            },
        },
    },

    viewapphb: function () {
        var action = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('test #options');
        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('crystal.view.apphb'));
        action.hide();
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
actionsheet: {
                selectors: 'options',
                id: 'actnopt',
                xtype: 'test',
                autoCreate: true,
            }
```

> Ext.getCmp('actnopt');

more info on [Action Sheet](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.ActionSheet)

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it works for me:

```
Ext.getCmp('btApagarCategoria').actions.hide();
```

where the **btApagarCategoria** is the button that invocate the actionsheet